# Java code to rename java packages

Tags: java, package, rename

Is it possible to rename a java package using java code? I need to do a lot of renaming in order to make a demonstration version of the system (without any real package and class names).
Java does not consider a java package to be a directory, so renameTo does not work...

Comment: You probably can by using `asm`. Like `ClassNode` and etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably could use [Jar Jar Links](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jarjar/) to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Intellij Idea feature. Right click on package in project tree, and use `Refactor -> Rename...`.